# How to add wp-cli to docker wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to do this without having to go into the container and install it? Seems kind of weird they wouldn't include this with the Wordpress image. Anyway - Heres what I have at the moment.
How would you do this?

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=admin
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '1234:80'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=admin
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=admin
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=admin
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=admin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the images tagged with `cli`, such as:

```
image: worpress:cli-php7.4
```

Find the list of available tags on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated)